# Could I add param in _init() function when using dlopen() api under linux?

Tags: c, linux, dlopen

Now I coding a loadable .so module under linux, I want to use `dlopen` in main program and use `_init()` in loadable .so module. My program like this:

main program:

```
...
dlopen(lib, flags);
...
```

loadable module:

```
#define MODULE_EXPORT(name, minit, mexit) \
    int __##name##_init(void) __attribute__((alias(#minit))); \
    void __##name##_exit(void) __attribute__((alias(#mexit)));

MODULE_EXPORT(dump, dump_init, dump_exit);

static int dump_init(void)
{
...
}
```

Now I want to add param into dump_init function, like this:

```
static int dump_init(const char *param){}
```

I don't know how to do this, or I could use another new api in linux? Thank you~

Comment: If you could do this, what would happen to the arguments given to a second call to `dlopen` that did not need to initialize your library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot pass arguments to a shared library initializer. If you need to pass parameters to your library, use a regular function.

(In your library's case, this should be simple -- remove the `MODULE_EXPORT` macro, and don't make `dump_init` static. Just call it normally from the host application.)

Generally speaking, you should avoid explicitly defining initializer and finalizer functions. They are primarily intended for internal use by the compiler, e.g. to call object initializers in C++.